# Table in smartphone layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a table with some images, and it's showed pretty good on the PC, but if i view my website with the smartphone the table is too large and it ruin all the mobile layout, there's some way to fix it?

This is the link so you can see the problem: http://www.animeshare.it/lista-anime/.

I'd like to fit the number of columns based on the screen width.

Comment: Purely css i would give the tr a class and add some css that changes on resolution change with css media queries

Comment: checkout https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: Like Sven B says I think media queries - e.g http://codepen.io/pixelchar/pen/rfuqK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really hard to do with a table layout. I'm not sure if you are required to use a table, but I would suggest using the CSS3 flex-box model instead for better mobile compatibility.

In the example below, the contents of the `#grid` div will wrap depending on the size of the `#grid` div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="grid">
        <div class="animeCell"><img src="" /><br />label 1</div>
        <div class="animeCell"><img src="" /><br />label 2</div>
        <div class="animeCell"><img src="" /><br />label 3</div>
        <div class="animeCell"><img src="" /><br />label 4</div>
        <div class="animeCell"><img src="" /><br />label 5</div>
        <div class="animeCell"><img src="" /><br />label 6</div>
        <div class="animeCell"><img src="" /><br />label 7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#grid {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
}

#grid .animeCell {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: center;
}

#grid .animeCell img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Please see my working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/z8h2py1r/1/), I hope it helps.

NOTE: Flex-box is not without bugs since it's a relatively new specification, you can learn more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: I'm gonna try it later, but this should work, thanks :D

Comment: I had to adapt it a bit since sometimes label were too wide and images are not all 150x200, but i made it work, so thanks for helping me :)